# memory overflow using the object list with generics

Tags: delphi, generics, memory, delphi-xe7

Step 1:
write an application with the code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Generics.Collections,
FMX.Types, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
TObjChild = class;

TObjTest = class
private

    FName: string;  
    FChilds: TList<TObjChild>;

public
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
    property Childs: TList<TObjChild> read FChilds write FChilds;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
end;

TObjChild = class
private

    FAdress: string;  
    FPostalCode: string;

public

    property Adress: string read FAdress write FAdress;
    property PostalCode: string read FPostalCode write FPostalCode;

end;

TForm1 = class(TForm)

    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

private
{ Private declarations }

public
{ Public declarations }

end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
{ TObjTeste }

constructor TObjTest.Create;
begin

    FChilds := TObjectList<TObjChild>.Create;

end;

destructor TObjTest.Destroy;
var

    i: integer;

begin

    for i := 0 to FChilds.count -1 do
    begin
        FChilds[I].Free;
    end;

    FreeAndNil(FChilds);
    inherited;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var

    I: Integer;
    ListObjs: TList<TObjTest>;
    lObjTeste: TObjTest;
    lObjChild: TObjChild;
    J: Integer;

begin

    ListObjs := TList<TObjTest>.Create;

    for I := 0 to 5000 do
    begin
        lObjTeste := TObjTest.Create;

        for J := 0 to 2000 do
        begin
            lObjChild := TObjChild.Create;
            lObjTeste.FChilds.Add(lObjChild)
        end;

        ListObjs.Add(lObjTeste);

    end;

    if MessageDlg('Delete objects?', TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0) = idOK then
    begin
        for I := 0 To ListObjs.Count - 1
        begin
            ListObjs[I].Free;
        end;

        FreeAndNil(ListObjs);
    end;

end;

end.
```

Step 2: Run application and press button1

After pressing the OK button messagedlg of the application does not release the memory

Step 3: Repeat steps sometimes the application returns a memory low

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Your outer loop is creating 5000 instances of TObjTest. Your inner loop is create 2000 instances of TObjChild for each list. That's ten million objects. Are you sure that's what you want to be doing?

Comment: @MikeSutton This is test code. I guess the runtime errors are more likely to happen when many objects are created. But the code would be broken even if just a single object was added to that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
constructor TObjTest.Create;
begin
  FChilds := TObjectList<TObjChild>.Create;
end;

destructor TObjTest.Destroy;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to FChilds.count - 1 do
  begin
    FChilds[i].Free;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(FChilds);
  inherited;
end;
```

By default `TObjectList<T>` takes ownership of its members. So you do not need to, and indeed should not, free the members in the destructor.

So here:

```
for i := 0 to FChilds.count - 1 do
begin
  FChilds[i].Free;
end;
```

you free the members. But then here:

```
FreeAndNil(FChilds);
```

The object list also frees the members. Who have already been freed. That double free leads to your runtime errors.

The fix is to remove the explicit freeing of the object list members and rely on the list to do the work:

```
destructor TObjTest.Destroy;
begin
  FChilds.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

This ownership of its members is the single reason for the existence of `TObjectList<T>`. That is the only functionality that it offers beyond that provided by `TList<T>`. Read about it here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList

Finally, the plural of child is children.

Comment: Using TObjectList the problem with memory is worse.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right.
Even with the TList is releasing the memory (if treated).
I think we missed something in the code that passed.

Comment: David Heffernam, Yes. The problem is you have expressed. Settled.